# Android Firebase Пустой List

Tags: android, firebase

Если смотреть данные внутри метода, то список заполнен, как только метод заканчивается - список становится пустым

```
private static ArrayList<String> companiesList = new ArrayList<String>();
private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestoreForCompanies;
firebaseFirestoreForCompanies = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
firebaseFirestoreForCompanies.collection("Companies").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
                    companiesList.add(String.valueOf(map.values()).substring(1, String.valueOf(map.values()).length() - 1));
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё дело в асинхронности вызова метода `onComplete`. Пока он не отработает, список будет пустым. И неважно, где в коде вы его проверяете, до начала метода или после.

Начинайте работу со списком только после того, как отработает этот callback метод. То есть из него (либо внутри):

```
private static ArrayList<String> companiesList = new ArrayList<String>();
...

// Здесь список пустой
firebaseFirestoreForCompanies.collection("Companies").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
            Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
            companiesList.add(String.valueOf(map.values()).substring(1, String.valueOf(map.values()).length() - 1));

            doSomething();
        }
    }
});
// И здесь список пустой, так как асинхронный метод ещё не отработал
...

private void doSomething() {
    // Здесь список заполнен, так как метод вызван после завершения асинхронного метода
}
```